# Unresolved variable PhpStorm in Vue.js syntax

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, phpstorm

I got very simple code:

```
<tr v-for="(log, index) in items" :key="index">
    <td>{{ log.user_name }}</td>
```

`log.user_name` is underlined and I see "Unresolved variable `user_name`". I know what to do if it would be function in `<script>`, but in HTML I have no idea.

Comment: Some default value in case it doesn't exist `<td>{{ log.user_name || 'N/A' }}</td>`

Comment: @kemicofa, I actually have that in code, I just reduced the code. It doesn;t work

Comment: Well, in general the issue is that PHPStorm is unable to figure out what "log" is. Have you installed the [vue.js plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/vue-js.html) ?

Comment: @kemicofa of course

Comment: works perfectly fine for me in 2019.2.3. If the error persists on caches invalidation (*File>Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*), please create a new support ticket, providing a complete code sample the issue can be reproduced with